# Hostname in docker compose file v3 is not accepted

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I am trying to set the hostname for the container as `hostname: '{{.Node.Hostname}}'` in docker compose v3 in AWS EC2.

It is failing as `Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = 3 desc = expanding hostname failed: template: expansion:1:7: executing "expansion" at <.Node.Hostname>: can't evaluate field Hostname in type struct { ID string }`.

Here are the version details,

```
Client:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   3dfb8343b139d6342acfd9975d7f1068b5b1c3d3
 Built:        Fri Nov 10 00:50:37 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.06.2-ce
 API version:  1.30 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.8.4
 Git commit:   402dd4a/17.06.2-ce
 Built:        Fri Nov 10 00:51:08 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

As per https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/, 17.06.+ is compatible with docker-compose v3.

How I can make this templating work? Do I need to upgrade the docker?
Thanks.

Comment: I think `.Node` here is giving you a Node ID and not a Node object. I am not sure which object are exposed to the templates though

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32561 maybe it will be available in latest docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now works with compose files and v17.12 (Dec 2017 stable release) of Docker, but only works when used with Swarm Stacks.

I think you're using Swarm so just update your docker version and you should be good, but here's more info for others in case they are just trying single node `docker-compose up`, which won't work with templates.

`docker-compose` [does not interpret go templates like Swarm does](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4964).

In addition, the `.Node.Hostname` is a Swarm-specific label, so you can't use it with `docker-compose up` on a single server, which doesn't have access to that label.

Just to verify, when I use this compose file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: '{{.Node.Hostname}}'
```

In docker-compose this is what I got:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec nginx hostname
{{.Node.Hostname}}
```

Then if I use that file in Swarm Stacks:

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml hn
# find the node and container ID of that service task
# found them on node 1 with hostname "swarm1"
docker exec 0a087 hostname
swarm1
```

If you need to use `docker-compose` in a single node and get the hostname into the compose file, maybe use [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution), then set the hostname to a variable and then `docker-compose up` will replace the variable in the compose file.

Comment: Thanks. I am using it in swarm mode, to deploy cadvisor in global mode